# Problemas com estruturas condicionais

Tags: python, condição, controle-de-fluxo

Comecei a programar a pouco tempo e estou fazendo alguns exercícios de Python.

O problema é que a variável resultado sempre retorna "Aprovado" mesmo quando o conceito é "D" ou "E".

Já quebrei muito a cabeça e não consigo enxergar o erro.

> Faça um programa que lê as duas notas parciais obtidas por um aluno numa disciplina ao longo de um semestre, e calcule a sua média. A atribuição de conceitos obedece à tabela abaixo:
>   Média de Aproveitamento  Conceito
>   Entre 9.0 e 10.0        A
>   Entre 7.5 e 9.0         B
>   Entre 6.0 e 7.5         C
>   Entre 4.0 e 6.0         D
>   Entre 4.0 e zero        E
>   O algoritmo deve mostrar na tela as notas, a média, o conceito correspondente e a mensagem “APROVADO” se o conceito for A, B ou C ou “REPROVADO” se o conceito for D ou E.

```
nota1=float(input("Digite nota 1: "))
nota2=float(input("Digite nota 2: "))
media=(nota1+nota2)/2
if media >=9:
   conceito = "A"
elif media >= 7.5:
   conceito = "B"
elif media >= 6:
    conceito = "C"
elif media >= 4:
    conceito = "D"
elif media >= 0:
    conceito = "E"
if conceito == "A" or "B" or "C":
    resultado = "Aprovado!"
elif conceito == "D" or "E":
    resultado = "Reprovado"
print("Nota 1: %.2f\nNota 2:%.2f"%(nota1,nota2))
print("Média: %.2f"%media)
print("Conceito: %s"%conceito)
print("Resultado: %s"%resultado)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas mude isso:

```
if conceito == "A" or "B" or "C":
    resultado = "Aprovado!"
elif conceito == "D" or "E":
    resultado = "Reprovado"
```

para isso:

```
if conceito == "A" or conceito == "B" or conceito == "C":
    resultado = "Aprovado!"
elif conceito == "D" or conceito == "E":
    resultado = "Reprovado"
```

ou se preferir:

```
if conceito in ("A","B","C"):
    resultado = "Aprovado!"
elif conceito in ("D", "E"):
    resultado = "Reprovado"
```

e pronto.

Comment: Antony, busque também explicar o motivo da alteração. Nem todos os usuários terão o nível de abstração suficiente para entender a diferença entre os códigos.

Answer (score 4):

> **Disclaimer**: É óbvio que o código pode ser um pouco mais idiomático e Pythônico sem precisar mudar muita coisa, mas, pra mim, não faz sentido tentar explicar isso agora porque como o AP disse (e também pela própria natureza da pergunta) ele está iniciando e tentando entender coisas básicas.
>
> Pra todo efeito, o código poderia ser assim
>
> ```
> resultado = "Aprovado!" if conceito in ("A", "B", "C") else "Reprovado"
> ```

---

O problema é que a condição não está certa, ela deveria ser assim.

```
if conceito == "A" or conceito == "B" or conceito == "C":
    resultado = "Aprovado!"
elif conceito == "D" or conceito == "E":
    resultado = "Reprovado"
```

Da forma que você escreveu, sempre vai cair no primeiro `if` porque você não compara o valor de `conceito` com `"B"` ou com `"C"`.

Você simplesmente joga os valores deles dentro da condição e `B` (assim como `C`) são interpretados como `true` pelo Python. Isso porque **qualquer** string não vazia é `true` para o Python.

[Você pode conferir este comportamento no repl.it.](https://repl.it/KQDb)

Ou seja, a condição que você escreveu poderia ser lida assim

> Se o valor de `conceito` for igual a "A" (`que é false`) **ou** se "B" (`que é true`) **ou** se "C" (`que também é true`), **faça** (...)

E ela deveria ser assim

> Se o valor de `conceito` for igual a "A" (`que é false`) **ou** se o valor de `conceito` for igual a "B" (`que é false`) **ou** se o valor de conceito for igual a "C" (`que é false`) **faça** (...)

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/KQDk)

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo o uso incorreto do das condições.
Faça assim :

```
nota1=float(input("Digite nota 1: "))
nota2=float(input("Digite nota 2: "))
media=(nota1+nota2)/2
if media >=9:
   conceito = "A"
elif media >= 7.5:
   conceito = "B"
elif media >= 6:
    conceito = "C"
elif media >= 4:
    conceito = "D"
else:               # Não é necessário utilizar o elif já que só resta uma opção 
    conceito = "E"
if conceito == "A" or "B" or "C":
    resultado = "Aprovado!"
else:                       #Mesma coisa aqui se conceito não é A,B,C é D ou E
    resultado = "Reprovado"
print("Nota 1: %.2f\nNota 2:%.2f"%(nota1,nota2))
print("Média: %.2f"%media)
print("Conceito: %s"%conceito)
print("Resultado: %s"%resultado)
```

Espero ter ajudado !

Comment: Por favor, poste o código em texto, não imagens.

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de tentar definir a "aprovação" pelas letras apos o processo de "conceito" você poderia trabalhar novamente com a media.

Assim ainda ficando um independente do outro.

```
nota1=float(input("Digite nota 1: "))
nota2=float(input("Digite nota 2: "))
media=(nota1+nota2)/2
if media >=9:
   conceito = "A"
elif media >= 7.5:
   conceito = "B"
elif media >= 6:
    conceito = "C"
elif media >= 4:
    conceito = "D"
elif media >= 0:
    conceito = "E"

resultado = "Aprovado!"
if media <= 4:
    resultado = "Reprovado"

print("Nota 1: %.2f\nNota 2:%.2f"%(nota1,nota2))
print("Média: %.2f"%media)
print("Conceito: %s"%conceito)
print("Resultado: %s"%resultado)
```