# Comparação de char em C

Tags: c, if, operadores, comparação, char

Preciso descobrir se cada elemento de uma lista encadeada é ou não uma vogal.

Como posso corrigir meu código?

```
int BuscaNv(LISTA* resp){
   NO* atual = resp->inicio; 

   while(atual){
    if(atual->letra == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'){
      printf("É vogal\n");
      atual = atual->prox;
    }
    else{
      printf("Não é vogal\n");
      atual = atual->prox;
    }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Typedefs:

```
typedef struct estr {
    char letra;
    struct estr *prox;
} NO;

typedef struct {
    NO *inicio;
} LISTA;
```

Comment: Por que não está conseguindo?

Comment: Código devolve "é vogal" para todos os caracteres

Comment: Estes `||` estão errados.

Comment: Veja, [esta publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/230333/18246). O problema é o mesmo que o seu, o que muda é a sintaxe da linguagem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essa sintaxe está completamente errada, tem que comparar a variável contra o caractere individualmente.

```
if (atual->letra == 'a' || atual->letra == 'e' || atual->letra == 'i' || atual->letra == 'o' || atual->letra <= 'u')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Char/ComparingInStruct.c).

Estava comparando a primeira expressão booleana contra caracteres. Um caractere que não é nulo é um valor diferente de 0, e no lógica booleana 0 é falso e todos os outros valore são verdadeiros, então já na segunda expressão depois do `||` sempre dará verdadeiro, que não é o desejado.

Answer (score 3):

Que tal utilizar uma função para verificar se a letra é uma vogal:

```
int eh_vogal( char c )
{
    int i = 0;
    static const char v[] = "aeiouAEIOU";

    while( v[i] )
        if( v[i++] == c )
            return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Com isso, seu código ficaria assim:

```
int BuscaNv(LISTA* resp){
    NO* atual = resp->inicio;

    while(atual){
        if(eh_vogal(atual->letra)){
            printf("É vogal\n");
            atual = atual->prox;
        }
        else{
            printf("Não é vogal\n");
            atual = atual->prox;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se voce fizer esse teu if assim funciona?

```
    if(atual->letra == 'a' ||
       atual->letra == 'e' ||
       atual->letra == 'i' ||
       atual->letra == 'o' ||
       atual->letra == 'u'){
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
```

Comment: A resposta do @bigown esta mais completa.